# $V$ Vector space, Q Skew Symmetric nondgenerate bilnear operator $\rightarrow$ \rightarrow $det(Q)=1$ and dimension of $V$ is even?

Tags: linear-algebra

Question: If $V$ Vector space, Q Skew Symmetric nondgenerate bilnear operator then show that that   $det(Q)=1$ and that dimension of $V$ is even.

My attempt at proof:

Since $Q$ is skew symmetric we have that $$Q^t=-Q$$  So $det(Q)=det(Q^t=det(-Q)=-det(Q)$ edit: WRONG!!! $det(-Q)=(-1)^ndet(Q)$

Hm.. But that's not right.. else $Det(Q)=0$.

Help appreciated!

Comment: $\det(-Q)=(-1)^n\det Q$

Comment: Where did we use nondegeneracy here??? To invert the matrix I bet, thanks!

Comment: Yes, which explains why the dimension must be even, since if $n$ is odd, $\det Q=0$.

Comment: Is the hypothesis strong enough to make $det(Q)=1$??? I'm not seeing why that must be true.

Comment: The determinant is not necessarily $1$. E.g. $\det\pmatrix{0&-a\\ a&0}=a^2$, which is not equal to $1$ when $a\ne\pm1$.

Comment: If $Q$ satisfies all of your hypotheses, then so does $cQ$ for any non-zero scalar $c$. So you have considerable freedom to change the determinant while maintaining your hypotheses (unless the only scalars are $0,1,-1$).